# jms:message-driven-channel-adapter should not poll for messages older than 30 mins

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

I want to poll for messages in a queue which are not older than 30 mins.

How do I do that with jms:message-driven-channel-adapter ?
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Such functionality is not supported by the JMS specification.

On the producer side, you can set a time to live on the message which will cause the message to be removed if not consumed within that time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a selector to query messages based on a timestamp header. But I have to say that selectors usualy don't have good performance.

A topic would be more apropriated for this kind of logic (message that expires after a while) but I don't know if it would be suitable to your business logic because a message in a topic is received by every consumer/listener subscribed.